# The program can't start because MSVCP90D.dll is missing from your computer

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Windows 7 x64; Visual Studio 2005-2012;

The Visual Studio 2012 was installed at my computer at first. But now I need the 2005, 2008, and 2010 too. I uninstalled the 2012 version (for the problems avoiding) and instal all in ascending order (with their SP): 2005, 2008, 2010, 2012.

I wrote test project in VS 2008 and tried compile it (Debug|x64 configuration), but I got an error in the "Error List" window:

> Error result 1 returned from 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe'.

But I see the exe file was created... If I try run it I get an error message:

> The program can't start because MSVCP90D.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

But the **MSVCP90D.dll** file are exists actualy into the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x86\Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT" and "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\amd64\Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT" directories.

Ok I change the project's property. I set the "**Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)**" value instead of "**Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)**" for the "C/C++->Code Generation->Runtime Library" property.

But I get the same error in the "Error List" window yet. I see the exe file was created again... **If I try to run this exe file, I see all works fine now**.

Why I get an error still in the "Error List"? Why I need to change that property? How can I solve this problem (an error message)?

Comment: Side-by-side configuration error.Hard to get rid of. Try to uninstall VC++2012, check again and reinstall 2012.

Comment: Do you have a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) to give us ? It will be easier to understand what it is going on...

Comment: Installation of these programs took two days for me. Their installing\uninstalling very long by time.

Comment: > Do you have a SSCCE to give us ?
My "hello world" sample sources is here: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7H_2Cq9tBXdSkNxd0tWZGxnWDQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several Google answers to query "Error result 1 returned from 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe'". First of them (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/871103ca-6015-40ce-8a59-92e47ce68aeb/error-prj0002-error-result-1-returned-from-cwindowssystem32cmdexe) suggests that you could disable AutoRun feature of the console. If you have AutoRun value in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor` registry key then rename it to something else, and see if the error is gone.

Apparently if there is a COLOR command in the AutoRun registry value then the error appears, but if AutoRun value has no COLOR command then there is no error. So you can have the AutoRun value in the registry, just remove the COLOR command from it to fix the problem.

Maybe this error has nothing to do with the other error ("missing" MSVCP90D.dll), but let's fix one thing at a time.

Comment: Thank you! Yes it solved my problem. I've renamed the `AutoRun` property in the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` registry key and an error disappeared.

Comment: It seems that COLOR command is somehow causing the problem, so you can restore your AutoRun line, and just remove the COLOR command. The main question now is if this fix also fixes your second problem ("missing" MSVCP90D.dll)?

Comment: @Bush I edited the answer to explain it. For more details read the discussion from the provided link .